# How to combine compass with bless?

Tags: css, node.js, compass-sass

I am working on a Compass project and my final css output is huge so it needs to be be [blessed](http://blesscss.com/) .

I am using Codekit to compile my SCSS files, and it has the bless option for the less and sass files but unluckly this option seems to be not available for the compass projects (BTW there is no workaround to fix the problem https://github.com/bdkjones/CodeKit/issues/163)

Is there an alternative way to do that automatically after the compiling process? Is it possible to watch the css file with nodejs and then bless it?

====================================================

**UPDATE**

I am not using Codekit anymore I use Grunt to build the project assets and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that using [this reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) you can simply do something like:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
    system('blessc ' + File.basename(filename))
end
```

after you have installed [Bless](http://blesscss.com/).

What it does is simply attaching that event after you compile your Compass file :) Enjoy

Comment: The binary is "blessc" and not "bless".

Comment: It works perfectly, I just had to set the right path to the css output: `on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
    exec('blessc ' + css_dir +  "/" + File.basename(filename) + " -f")
end`

Comment: For some reason this is now not working for me.  Perhaps something changed with my version of CodeKit... It used to work, but now doesn't....

Comment: It's not working for me either. I'm generating a "No such file or directory" error. The path is correct as I've hardcoded it, and copied the exact path out of the error and ran it in terminal which works. Do you think it could be a delay between the stylesheet saving, and the callback firing - ie, at the time the callback fires the css files hasn't completely compiled?

Comment: Any idea how to stop this causing a `compass watch` to exit?

Comment: Found the answer! Use `system` instead of `exec`

Answer (score 1):

This works for the regular compile command, but it doesn't work when you watch it. After Bless is completed the watch process ends.

Answer (score 0):

I found that blessc just wouldn't execute, I'd get one of these two errors:

> config.rb: No such file or directory - blessc (whatever filename)

or

> env: node: No such file or directory

It turns out this is because blessc/node.js are installed in /usr/local/bin, and that is not in the PATH variable for ruby exec (/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin). The following code worked:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  exec('PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; blessc ' + filename + ' -f')
end
```

Edited to add: If after this you get errors saying that the files aren't css from bless, check if your absolute path to the file contains white space. You can escape the white space by doing the following:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  exec('PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; blessc ' + (filename.gsub! ' ', '\ ') + ' -f')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code block, I've made couple of changes of [Julian Xhokaxhiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518095/julian-xhokaxhiu) answer:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  begin
    puts "Counting number of selector in :: " + filename
    result = system('blessc',filename,'-f')

    if not result
      Kernel.exit(false)
    else
      puts "Blessed the file to support Older version of IE."
    end

  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Please install bless.\nsudo npm install -g bless."
    Kernel.exit(false)
  end
end
```